# Unable to show spinner using spin.js after clicking button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to fade out the submit button after the user clicks on it, and I want to replace it with a loading icon. I'm using the [spin.js](http://spin.js.org/) library

### This is my button:

```
<button type="submit" name="inscripcionUsuarioForm" id="botonSubmit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" onclick="ocultarSubmit();" >Inscribirme ahora</button>
<div id="spinner"></div>
```

### And this is my function inside formularios.js

```
function ocultarSubmit() {
  $('#botonSubmit').fadeOut();
var opts = {
  lines: 13 // The number of lines to draw
, length: 28 // The length of each line
, width: 14 // The line thickness
, radius: 42 // The radius of the inner circle
, scale: 1 // Scales overall size of the spinner
, corners: 1 // Corner roundness (0..1)
, color: '#000' // #rgb or #rrggbb or array of colors
, opacity: 0 // Opacity of the lines
, rotate: 0 // The rotation offset
, direction: 1 // 1: clockwise, -1: counterclockwise
, speed: 0.6 // Rounds per second
, trail: 60 // Afterglow percentage
, fps: 20 // Frames per second when using setTimeout() as a fallback for CSS
, zIndex: 2e9 // The z-index (defaults to 2000000000)
, className: 'spinner' // The CSS class to assign to the spinner
, top: '50%' // Top position relative to parent
, left: '50%' // Left position relative to parent
, shadow: true // Whether to render a shadow
, hwaccel: false // Whether to use hardware acceleration
, position: 'absolute' // Element positioning
}
var spinner = new Spinner(opts).spin();
$("#spinner").append(spinner.el);
}
```

And I'm calling the file at the very end of the page:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/spin.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/formularios.js"></script>
```

The button gets faded out but the spin wheel won't appear. The console won't show any errors. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: I have made a Demo that works...
https://plnkr.co/edit/sm3XkRNJB9ufNRiklU6z?p=preview

Try to run it without the other redundant libraries you load for this purpose

Comment: you probably shouldn't declare the spin.js options array inside the function you call on click.. I re-wrote it using cleaner JS, works (my answer below)

Comment: Use this https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js
Just add a "s".

Comment: @Rosamunda : please comment/vote accept answers if you think they helped you.

Answer (score -1):

Move the opts array, outside of the `ocultarSubmit` function, avoid inline JS:

```js
var opts = {
  lines: 13 // The number of lines to draw
, length: 28 // The length of each line
, width: 14 // The line thickness
, radius: 42 // The radius of the inner circle
, scale: 1 // Scales overall size of the spinner
, corners: 1 // Corner roundness (0..1)
, color: '#000' // #rgb or #rrggbb or array of colors
, opacity: 0.25 // Opacity of the lines
, rotate: 0 // The rotation offset
, direction: 1 // 1: clockwise, -1: counterclockwise
, speed: 1 // Rounds per second
, trail: 60 // Afterglow percentage
, fps: 20 // Frames per second when using setTimeout() as a fallback for CSS
, zIndex: 2e9 // The z-index (defaults to 2000000000)
, className: 'spinner' // The CSS class to assign to the spinner
, top: '50%' // Top position relative to parent
, left: '50%' // Left position relative to parent
, shadow: false // Whether to render a shadow
, hwaccel: false // Whether to use hardware acceleration
, position: 'absolute' // Element positioning
}
$('body').on('click', '#botonSubmit', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('in');
  var target = document.getElementById('spinner')
  var spinner = new Spinner(opts).spin(target);  
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://spin.js.org/spin.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="submit" name="inscripcionUsuarioForm" id="botonSubmit" class="fade in btn btn-primary text-center">Inscribirme ahora</button>
<div id="spinner"></div>
```